# SQL query to include time segments with no counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am working in SQL Server 2014. I have table that records 'counts' and a timestamp of the count. The counting period is a two hour block that can start at any quarter hour. In the example data below, the count starts at 16:00 and goes through 18:00. The counting block could have started at 01:30 and stopped at 03:30.

```
Timestamp   Count
16:00:31    1
16:00:42    1
16:16:04    1
16:16:06    1
16:45:10    1
16:45:31    1
16:45:32    1
17:16:45    1
17:16:52    1
17:16:53    1
17:33:19    1
17:34:01    1
17:45:03    1
17:46:08    1
```

I have a query which sums the counts over 15 minute intervals within the two hour block:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(DATEPART(HOUR, [Timestamp]), '0#') + ':' + FORMAT(DATEPART(MINUTE, [TimeStamp]) / 15 * 15, '0#') AS QtrHrBeg
    , COUNT(*) AS CountTotal
FROM 
    [Sandbox].[trippetoe].[SURVEYCOUNTS]
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR, [TIMESTAMP])
    , (DATEPART(MINUTE, [TIMESTAMP]) / 15 * 15)
```

which results in this:

```
QtrHrBeg    Count
16:00   2
16:15   2
16:45   3
17:15   3
17:30   2
17:45   2
```

I'd like to include 15 minute intervals where there are no counts - in this example the quarter hours beginning at 16:30 and 17:00, like below:

```
QtrHrBeg    Count
16:00   2
16:15   2
16:30   0
16:45   3
17:00   0
17:15   3
17:30   2
17:45   2
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below.

Begin by creating a time table of all intervals for the day, then restricting that to the intervals for the 2 hour window you want.

Then left join that to the sum of your data table, pushing 0 where the join returns null.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ([TimeStamp] TIME, [Count] INT)
INSERT INTO @Data ([TimeStamp],[Count])
VALUES ('16:00:31',1),
       ('16:00:42',1),
       ('16:16:04',1),
       ('16:16:06',1),
       ('16:45:10',1),
       ('16:45:31',1),
       ('16:45:32',1),
       ('17:16:45',1),
       ('17:16:52',1),
       ('17:16:53',1),
       ('17:33:19',1),
       ('17:34:01',1),
       ('17:45:03',1),
       ('17:46:08',1)

;with AllIntervals AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(TIME,'00:00:00') AS Interval
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,15,Interval)
    FROM AllIntervals
    WHERE Interval<'23:45:00'
), MyIntervals AS
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Interval,108) AS Interval
        FROM AllIntervals
        WHERE Interval >= (SELECT MIN(CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,0,[TimeStamp])/15)*15,0))) FROM @Data)
          AND Interval < DATEADD(HOUR,2,(SELECT MIN(CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,0,[TimeStamp])/15)*15,0))) FROM @Data))
    )

SELECT M.Interval, ISNULL(I.[Count],0)
FROM MyIntervals M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,0,[TimeStamp])/15)*15,0)) AS Interval, SUM([Count]) AS Count
           FROM @Data
           GROUP BY CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,0,[TimeStamp])/15)*15,0))) I
   ON M.Interval=I.Interval
```

Comment: `17:15   2` in the OP desired outputs wile it's `17:15  3` in yours.

Comment: @Sami Check his source data example.  It's 3 in there... 17:16:45, 17:16:52 and 17:16:53

Comment: I updated the original data example for the 17:15 segment.

Comment: @JiggsJedi I needed to change the WHERE statement in MyIntervals to `AND Interval <= DATEADD....` to work with my complete data set. Otherwise its works great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

1. Find the minimum date and the maximum date in the data you are going to work on , then round these two values to the nearest 15
2. Split the segment into 15 minutes intervals
3. Left join your data with the result came out and apply group by the StartTime and I used format in order to show the time formatting only

The benefit of this approach is that it works on specific interval and will not take any time interval outside of your data ranges.

```
with initial as(
  select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,min([Time])) / 15 * 15, 0) as MinTime,
         dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,max([Time])) / 15 * 15, 0) as MaxTime
  from data
 ), times as(
   select StartTime = MinTime,
          EndTime =dateadd(millisecond,-1,dateadd(minute,15,MinTime)),
          MaxTime
   from initial
   union all
   select dateadd(millisecond,1,EndTime),
          dateadd(minute,15,EndTime),
          MaxTime
   from times
   where EndTime<MaxTime
 )

 select format(t.StartTime,'HH:mm') as [Time],isnull(sum(d.[Count]),0) as [Count]
 from times t
 left join data d on d.[Time] between t.StartTime and t.EndTime
 group by t.StartTime
```

Here is the output

```
Time    Count
16:00   2
16:15   2
16:30   0
16:45   3
17:00   0
17:15   3
17:30   2
17:45   2
```

Here a working [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/769ca/3)

Hope this will help you

**EDIT**

I changed the usage of `second` to `millisecond` based on the comment from @HABO, it will solve the case where there is some times like `16:59:59`

Comment: What about all of the samples that fall into the one second gaps between intervals? Using a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) would address the issue and clarify the code: don't subtract one second when calculating `EndTime` and use `... on t.StartTime <= d.[Time] and d.[Time] < t.EndTime ...` for the range check.

Comment: Thanks for the good comment, I used `millisecond` which is enough for the question above, it gives high accuracy if the user cares about Hours ,minutes, and seconds which I believe is the case

Comment: That's why I suggested changing it the clear way. Try `declare @Foo as DateTime = '2017-07-01 12:00:00.000'; select @Foo, DateAdd( millisecond, -1, @Foo );`. Then read about "accuracy" for [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql). You need to subtract 3 milliseconds to make a difference.

Comment: I tip my hat for you :)

Comment: I should use `DateTime2` instead in my demo

Comment: @Monah I made the change suggested by @HABO and changed your WHERE statement in the 'UNION ALL' piece of code to `WHERE endtime <= MaxTime` to get all the cases in my complete data set. Works great.

Comment: @tripper great then, if my answer helped you and solved your issue, kindly vote up and mark as answer

Comment: @Monah I up-voted your answer, but i dont have enough reputation points for the up-vote to show.  Both of the provided responses worked for me. I marked the response by JiggsJedi as the answer solely because it was the first answer.